# Spring @Order annotation not loading in correct order

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot embedded tomcat.
In my application I have three configuration classes and I have used the `@Order` annotation to control the loading order of classes. When I run the application in embedded Tomcat it's working fine, but in standalone Tomcat (WAR) it's not loading in the correct order.
My classes are like below :

```
@Order(1) public Class WebConfig 
@Order(2) public Class SwaggerConfig
@Order(3) public Class PlanoutConfig
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@Order` defines the sort order for annotated components, not for configuration classes.
I suppose that in embedded Tomcat mode, you benefit from a side effect.

If your classes are configuration classes, that is, classes
annotated with `@Configuration`, the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-understanding-auto-configured-beans) states that
 you should favor `@AutoconfigureOrder` over `@Order`.

> **44.1 Understanding auto-configured beans**
>
> If you want to order certain auto-configurations that shouldn’t have
>   any direct knowledge of each other, you can also use
>   `@AutoconfigureOrder`. That annotation has the same semantic as the
>   regular `@Order` annotation but provides a dedicated order for
>   auto-configuration classes.

---

**[AutoConfigureOrder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfigureOrder.html)**

> ```
> public @interface AutoConfigureOrder
> ```
>
> Auto-configuration specific variant of Spring Framework's Order
>   annotation. Allows auto-configuration classes to be ordered among
>   themselves without affecting the order of configuration classes passed
>   to AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.register(Class...).

You could so write :

```
@AutoConfigureOrder(0) public Class WebConfig {...}
@AutoConfigureOrder(1) public Class SwaggerConfig {...}
@AutoConfigureOrder(2) public Class PlanoutConfig {...}
```